# p:first-line | w/ parent #div. 3rd Paragraph Tag or Other Selector

Tags: html, css

Although this syntax does not render, this is basically what I am attempting to do.

```
#description > p:first-line[title*='bandCopy'] {font-weight:bold;}
```

I want the first main body copy to have a **first-line bold.**

I am working with this page: 
http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/entertainers/smiths.php

*I am trying to use some CSS3 just for practice.*

**Thanks A Bunch!**

Comment: Are you having a problem with a specific browser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
#description>p[title*=bandCopy]:first-line {font-weight:bold;}
```

Comment: +1: its always better to enclose the *Attribute Selector* value in parenthesis. `E[att*="string"] {property: value;}` where E is a selector.

Comment: Side Question: Why isn't this working "p[title*="Dustree"]:first-line {font-weight:bold;}" ON THIS PAGE : http://www.glustik.com/dustreeproductions/company.php

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add `title="Dustree"` to the `<p>` tag :)

Comment: ZOMG. I was testing with "index.php" not "company.php". *Doh* Thank You for the Time.